# Add plugin to installer list

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to add my plugin to the available list in the installer. 
Currently there are 56 plugins to choose from
Is it possible a plugin to the list?

Answer (score 0):

See the [SimpleUpdateSite Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SimpleUpdateSite+Plugin):

> This plugin make Jenkins connect to the custom support site which provide custom plugin update info and announcements.

After installation there will be two new sections:

- *Manage Jenkins* → *Configure System* → ***Configure SimpleUpdater***
- *Manage Jenkins* → *Manage Plugins* → *Advanced* → ***Other sites***

Comment: I don't understand how this solves my issue. of course I can add my plugin after Jenkins installation through Manage Plugins section but I want it to be available in the installer

Comment: @Tsahi _Manage Jenkins_ → _Manage Plugins_ → _Available_ (list) is the place where plugins are usually installed. What do you exactly mean by "[installer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Native+Packages)"? If I run e.g. `jenkins.msi` of Jenkins 2.0 for Windows here there's no plugin list to choose from. If one deploys the `jenkins.war` directly there's not even an installer. Maybe it helps to extend your question to contain more than two sentences.

Comment: I found the answer here: 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+Selection+for+the+Setup+Dialog